# $(document.width).bind(onchange,...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Will this work?

The reason I ask is because I want to animate two elements that calculate their end location based on the width of the document. If the window or document size is changed I want to reset the animation.

Any suggestions or other methods that might work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `resize`: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Does this work on `document`? The api only says it works on `window`.

Comment: I think window is what he is looking for, that us basically the size of the viewport. The plugin you answered with is for when a DOM object resizes, like a div, which is cool too but I don't think that was the original question

Answer (score 1):

Use `.resize()` instead

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function()  {
    alert('changed');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on a `document` instead of on `window`, you need a plugin. I found this one on the jquery api in a comment:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/